# Error message, for "pip install /path/to/the/skimulator/directory" on Windows 10 Anaconda/python

Tags: python, error, climate, anaconda

I am trying to install [skimulator](https://forum.oceandatalab.com/thread-3.html) on my windows 10 system. This is for simulating images of sea ice drift in the Arctic, for 2025 satellite mission. I have installed Anaconda/python and followed the instructions:

" Install in an environment with `python 3`, `Numpy` and `Scipy` and `NetCDF4` (with `Conda` for instance)
https://git.oceandatalab.com/skim/skimulator . Dowload the zip file from this link, then you should do :

```
pip install /path/to/the/skimulator/directory  "
```

How do I install using `pip install`...? I obtain the following error message in the Anaconda prompt:

```
Directory of C:\Users\pclink\Documents\skimulator\skimulator.git

22/11/2018  14:32    <DIR>          .
22/11/2018  14:32    <DIR>          ..
22/11/2018  14:32               104 .gitignore
22/11/2018  14:32               320 CHANGES.txt
22/11/2018  14:32            35,149 COPYING
22/11/2018  14:32    <DIR>          data
22/11/2018  14:32    <DIR>          doc
22/11/2018  14:32    <DIR>          example
22/11/2018  14:32                84 MANIFEST.in
22/11/2018  14:32             1,948 README
22/11/2018  14:32               353 README.md
22/11/2018  14:32                82 requirements.txt
22/11/2018  14:32             4,144 setup.py
22/11/2018  14:32    <DIR>          skimulator
22/11/2018  14:32    <DIR>          test
               8 File(s)         42,184 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  251,200,610,304 bytes free

(base) C:\Users\pclink\Documents\skimulator\skimulator.git>pip install C:\Users\pclink\Documents\skimulator\
Directory 'C:\\Users\\pclink\\Documents\\skimulator\\' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

Is it better to install using `python setup.py install`? I tried this before and it didn't install correctly. It left me only with the `skimulator.git` directory with no required `MyParam` directory created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which specific version of Python do you have installed?  In Python 3.4 or later Pip is included with the Python installation.  If you have Pip installed you can just go to a Windows command line and enter  *pip install /path/to/the/skimulator/directory*

If you have an earlier version of Python you can install Pip. [Here are some links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) to get you started.

Alternatively you can install your package using the setup.py file included with the package you downloaded.  In this case you would need to open a Windows command prompt in the directory that has you setup.py file. Then enter.

```
set path=%path%;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\
```

Of course you would need to change the path from C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\ to the directory that stores you python.exe file. The image below shows the directory tree to my python.exe.
You can confirm that you have the correct path by entering

```
python
```

Finally enter the text below to install the package

```
python setup.py install
```

[image]

Comment: I have Python 3.7.0   .